# Outlook Anywhere and Outlook 2013

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, windows-8-mail-app

Is it possible for an Exchange admin to disable thick client access using Outlook Anywhere to an Exchange 2010 box (or to otherwise achieve that)?

I'm wondering whether that might explain the following symptoms:
I can access Exchange from an iPhone or Android, and also through the Windows 8 native mail app, but Outlook 2013 refuses to connect using Outlook Anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to limit Access to a mailbox using EMS:

`Set-CASMailbox -Identity "mailbox" -MapiEnabled:$false`

Your iPhone, Android and Windows 8 Mail App all are using Exchange ActiveSync protocol.

Please check also, whether your Outlook Provider is correctly configured for your SSL certificate:

`Get-OutlookProvider`

The Parameter `CertPrincipalName` should contain a value like `msstd:sslcertifcate_cn` like `msstd:example.com`.

Also make sure the Outlook Anywhere Virtual Directory (Get-OutlookAnywhere) is configured with the right settings for Hostnames.

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours trying to figure this out but it ended up being the opposite apparently MAPI is required for outlook anywhere in exchange 2013 sp1 it also disabled for all mailboxes by default. to turn it on you need to use ECP and select recipients then mailbox and then edit the mailbox. Then go ot mailbox features on the left. scroll down to MAPI and if its disabled enable it. That fixed it for me. alternatevely you can run the command Set-CASMailbox -Identity "mailbox" -MapiEnabled:$true